# Function of Display File Record minor issue in C

Tags: c, display

I am new to C language, currently I am working on a program which is a pharmacy system which included insert,update,delete,search,display function for it.
Everything work fine, except display. For example, my struct included Medicode,Mediname,Compname,Date,etc.
When i inserted a string which is over 7 alphabet, the alignment of the display will change, and make the display can't align well.

Display Issue will be shown in the image

[image]

```
void displayall()
{
    int emp;
    emp = empty();
    if (emp == 0)
    {
        printf("\nSorry, the file is empty.\n");
        getch();
    }
    if (emp != 0)
    {   
        FILE *fp1;
        fp1 = fopen("Medicine", "r");


printf("\nMediCode\tMedicineName\tCompanyName\tDateOfManufacture\tDateOfExpiry\t\tPrice\n\n");
            while (fread(&medi, sizeof(medi), 1, fp1))
                printf("%d\t\t%s\t\t%s\t\t%d\t\t\t%d\t\t        %.2f\n", medi.medicode, medi.mediname, medi.compname, medi.DateOM, medi.DateOE, medi.price);
            fclose(fp1);
            printf("\n\nPress any key to return to Main Menu.");
            getch();
        }
    }
```

Comment: just don't use *spaces* in `printf` and it'll be grand!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should read more about `printf` format to control the integer width and align.

More specific here: https://alvinalexander.com/programming/printf-format-cheat-sheet